# Jquery slider. Two digits on minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting

I have jquery slider and I want to select time from to. But minutes from 0-9 showing as `13:7` but not `13:07`

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#slider-time').slider({
        range: true,
        min: 300,
        max: 1280,
        step: 1,
        values: [ 300, 793 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            var hours1 = Math.floor(ui.values[0] / 60);
            var minutes1 = ui.values[0] - (hours1 * 60);

            if(hours1.length < 10) {hours1= '0' + hours};
            if(minutes1.length < 10) {minutes1 = '0' + minutes};

            if(minutes1 == 0) minutes1 = '00';

            var hours2 = Math.floor(ui.values[1] / 60);
            var minutes2 = ui.values[1] - (hours2 * 60);

            if(hours2.length < 10) {hours2= '0' + hours};
            if(minutes2.length < 10) {minutes2 = '0' + minutes};

            if(minutes2 == 0) minutes2 = '00';

            jQuery('#amount-stop').val(hours1+':'+minutes1 );
            jQuery('#amount-start').val(hours2+':'+minutes2 );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Numbers don't have a length, use something like `if(minutes2 < 10)`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following code to calculate hour and minute values

```
var hours1 = parseInt(ui.values[0] / 60 % 24, 10);
var minutes1 = parseInt(ui.values[0] % 60, 10);
```

In my case they return the values in two digits.

Answer (score 1):

Including the suggestion in my comment ("Numbers don't have a length, use something like: `if(minutes2 < 10)`"), also maybe make a `function timeToString()` to reduce repeated code and enhance manageability, e.g.:

```
function timeToString(time){
    var hours = Math.floor(time / 60),
        minutes = time - (hours * 60);

    if(hours < 10) {hours= '0' + hours};
    if(minutes < 10) {minutes = '0' + minutes};

    if(minutes == 0) minutes = '00';
    return hours + ":" + minutes;
}
```

and use that within your block, e.g.:

```
jQuery('#amount-stop').val( timeToString(ui.values[0]) );
jQuery('#amount-start').val( timeToString(ui.values[1]) );
```